# usage of !(not) operator in switch case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, operator-keyword, not-operator

```js
// checking whether a number is a multiple of 3 or not 
for (let number = 1; number <= 100; number++) {
  switch (number % 3) {
    case !0: // Here I have used !(not) but it's not helping, I only want to know why '!' is not helping           
      console.log(`${number} is not multiple of 3`);
      break;

    default:
      console.log(`${number} is multiple of 3`)
  }
}
```

Here the 1st case is not working. Code execution has no problems but the 1st case is not helping at all. The complete flow is going to the 'default:' code block only. Whenever the remainder is not equal to 0, the 1st case's code block should be executed, but it's always going to the default code block.

Comment: That's not how switch case statement works. Use a if-else

Comment: Just switch the console.logs and get rid of the ! Then it should work fine

Comment: Yep, using a switch statement there definitely doesn't make much sense. Even less if you only have two branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!0` evals to `true`, which is not equals to `1` or `2`.

Consider writing it in this way:

```js
for (let number = 1; number <= 100; number++) {
 switch (number % 3) {
  case 0:
   console.log(`${number} is multiple of 3`)
   break;
  default:
   console.log(`${number} is not multiple of 3`);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing the exact misunderstanding I had in my mind that `!0` is actually a boolean value :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in this way because !0 is always true in JavaScript so the loop always enters in the first case

Try it in this way

```
for (let number = 1; number <= 100 ;number++ ) {
  if(number % 3){
    console.log(`${number} is not multiple of 3`); 
  }
  else{
    console.log(`${number} is multiple of 3`); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to use 'switch' exclusively.

Comment: It's a pretty weird case for use switch but you're free to do it in any possible way ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` statement receives values on `case` statements, not expressions like the `if`. So, when js run your code, it will evaluate `!0` to `true` (inverse of a falsy value is true).

You must replace your switch by `if` and `elses`:

```
for (let number = 1; number <= 100 ;number++ ) {
    if ((number % 3) !== 0) {
         console.log(`${number} is not multiple of 3`); 
    } else {
         console.log(`${number} is multiple of 3`)
    }
}
```

But you can still use a switch case statement if you invert the logic:

```
for (let number = 1; number <= 100 ;number++ ) {
   switch (number % 3) {
     case 0:      
         console.log(`${number} is multiple of 3`)
     break;
     default:
         console.log(`${number} is not multiple of 3`); 
  }
}
```

But really makes no sense using a switch case in this situation since an `if-else` is much simpler and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

In JS, 0 is considered *falsy* that's why `!0` will equals `true` ( not falsy ).

As for your switch, you could  *reverse* your it and use a `true` as the switch values. The cases would then have the expression to check

```
for (let number = 1; number <= 100 ;number++ ) {
   switch (true) {
     case number % 3:        
         console.log(`${number} is not multiple of 3`); 
     break;

     default:
         console.log(`${number} is multiple of 3`)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that makes sense. You don't have a case for `true`. It will always go into the default case. Passing a constant value to a switch, doesn't make sense in any case.

Comment: @nicolas Thanks for answering! My confusion was that `!0` is just like comparing( ' ! == 0 ') but I get it now that it is actually a boolean value. Also in your code you have put true in your switch which is a boolean value but in the 1st case you have put number % 3 which returns a numerical value specifically 1 or 2. So, a boolean value can never be equal to a numerical value. That is why your code is not producing the desired o/p.  you can just change the true you put in the switch to 0. and then use the underlying code block to log that 3 is a multiple of 3.